# FakeS3 putObject not uploading file

Tags: java, file, amazon-s3, cloud

I am trying to test AmazonS3 API using FakeS3. I have installed it and started it as the instructions say to do. When I run the code, the server responds and the log shows no errors. The bucket is created in the specified directory. However, the file is not present in the directory. Instead, there is another directory that has the name keyName. No file is present inside this directory. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.io.File;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.S3ClientOptions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;

public class FileUpload {
    private static String bucketName     = "bucket1";
    private static String keyName        = "File1";
    private static String uploadFileName = "message.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //create a new AmazonS3Client object
        BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("foo", "bar");
        AmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
        client.setEndpoint("http://localhost:10000");
        client.setS3ClientOptions(newS3ClientOptions().withPathStyleAccess(true));
        System.out.println("Creating a new bucket......");
        client.createBucket(bucketName); //create a new bucket
        System.out.println("Uploading text file into specified bucket......");
        File fin = new File(uploadFileName);
        client.putObject(bucketName, keyName, fin); 
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Example server log:

```
st - - [09/Jul/2015:19:10:56 CDT] "PUT /bucket1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
- -> /bucket1/
localhost - - [09/Jul/2015:19:10:56 CDT] "PUT /bucket1/File1 HTTP/1.1" 200 0
- -> /bucket1/File1
```

Comment: I have the same problem, did you manage to find a solution ?

Comment: If you put a file and list, read it it will work fine.Irrespective of the folder structure it is storing in the localhotst.
Just put a file and list,read its content. It will work as expected (ignore the folder structure it is saved)